# distributed / multi branch / gateway setup with celery possible?

Tags: celery

I'm interested to try out Celery the distributed task queue for python.

In our scenario we have multiple branches which each would have a RabbitMQ server running and I would like to be able to execute tasks between branches.

e.g. in branch A I queue task B with RabbitMQ instance C.
What needs to happen now is that the task B gets forwarded from instance C to RabbitMQ instance D running in another branch E. In branch E then a worker process picks up the task, responds back when its done etc.

Are there examples on the internet outlining how to set this up please or would you know if this works?

It does look like the Federation / Shovel features of RabbitMQ are the way to go but was wondering if anybody has used Celery / RabbitMQ in this scenario yet?

Thanks a lot,
Patrick

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at

- Federation
  http://www.rabbitmq.com/federation.html
- Shovel
  http://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html

Comment: Thanks I did look at them beforehand. Was just looking if someone had production experience with the setup. Updated my question above